# Sublime Text 3 keeps crashing with "error: plugin_host has exited unexpectedly"

Tags: windows-7, windows, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

I'm using Windows 7 and Sublime Text 3 (build 3103). Sometimes it spontaneously throws an error and plugins stop working. Here's the error:

```
error: plugin_host has exited unexpectedly, plugin functionality won't be available until Sublime Text has been restarted
```

Here's full log from my Sublime Text's console: http://pastebin.com/sg07vdGk

What I've tried so far:

- Reinstalling ST
- Updating ST and all plugins
- Removing most of my plugins

I only have the most necessary plugins installed and the error still happens. Is there a way to debug which plugin causes it?

I've seen people mention that the error can happen, because of incorrect permission on folders, but it seems unlikely on Windows.

Any ideas on how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You must have css extended completions. That was the case of the problem in my case. Go to **Preferences** > **Package settings** and disable it.

Answer (score -1):

:) Probably it will help you.

I was with the same error on my Sublime Text 3 (3114), and after search a lot about the error messenge, about permissions on folders and other things... I've just removed all my plugins that I installed, and I reinstalled one by one, testing if the error appeared again, untill I installed the "CSS Extended Completions" and the error returns again. So It's only u do this, like me.

I hope it helped you...